# Instantiation of component class Yii

Tags: php, yii, components

I'm trying to understand a sequence of instatiation component class. As I understood an application component class has a lazy initialization (I've logged starting invokation of `init()` method). Let I've created a simple test component called `document`:

```
class Document extends CApplicationComponent{
        private $_width='150';
        public function init(){
            echo "This is document component init method.";
        }
        public function getWidth(){
            return $this->_width;
        }
    }
```

I've add a corresponding component's array to the `config.php`:

```
'components'=>array(
            'document' => array( 'class' => 'document')
        )
```

And it works, but I dont understand the sense. Actually, let we renamed component's file from `Document.php` to `DDocument.php`. Exception is raised after this renaming. **Why?** We doesn't renaming component's class name which specified in config.php. And what does keys of components array mean? Is it just property of `Yii::app()` object which are instances of `CApplicationComponent`?

Comment: Can anyone tell me How to add custom row in yii Cgridview sorry to ask here because i am newbie to stackoverflow and when i click on ask question it goes to help center

Comment: @GauravParashar You must apply the site rules and further you can ask your question.